# Nested For Loop Stops Midstream

Tags: excel, vba, nested

In the code below LastCellR = 49 and LastSheet is 61 (i.e. there are 61 sheets in the workbook and 49 client names in column 1 of the active sheet)
The code runs fine till i gets to 46 and CS gets to 61. Then in Debug, the code stops and highlights
"If Worksheets(CS).Name = ClientName Then".

The goal here is to go down a list of client names and determine if they are existing clients or new ones.  So I simply get each client's name and search through the sheet names in the workbook.
Any ideas why it stops dead in it's tracks?

Thanks for any insight you can provide.

```
For i = 2 To LastCellR
    ClientName = Cells(i, 1).Value
    If Trim(ClientName) = "" Then Exit Sub

' Check for existing client
    For CS = 1 To LastSheet
        If Worksheets(CS).Name = ClientName Then
           NewClient = False
           Exit For
        End If
    Next CS
Next i
```

Comment: What is the value in `Cells(46, 1)`?

Comment: The value in cells(46,1) is "Young and Associates".  There are 61 sheets. There is no error message the simulation simply stops with the code referenced highlighted.

Comment: Is the `Activesheet` in the same workbook as the other 61 worksheets? What is its name? Which of the worksheets are in the workbook containing this code?

Comment: Does it work if you press F5 after it stops?  Sometimes phantom break points get saved that dont cause error messages like normal.

Answer (score 1):

Not the answer to your issues, may be another option to check for the sheet

```
Public Function WorksheetExists(strName As String) As Boolean
On Error GoTo eHandle

Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

WorksheetExists = True

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strName)

Set ws = Nothing

Exit Function

eHandle:

    WorksheetExists = False
    Resume Next
    
End Function
```

Then `newclient = not worksheetexists(clientname)`

Comment: If you would move `WorksheetExists = True` below `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strName)`, you could remove `WorksheetExists = False`, but you would have to add a label (e.g. `ProgExit`) before `Exit Function` and do `Resume ProgExit` which would result in the same number of lines. Your solution avoids using another label, which is a valuable lesson for me. Thx. While I am not aware of any flaws in your code, there are two minor details that are 'puzzling' me: Why `Excel.Worksheet` instead of just `Worksheet` and Is `Set ws = Nothing` really necessary and why? Would appreciate the feedback.